# Manipulate form data in controller to create new field - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Noob question here but I think it could help others as well,

Im taking data from a form (in the view) and in my controller I want to use this field :initialgpa and create a new field :normalisedgpa and then pass it back to the database. However A) my database never updates and B) when I add the multiply by 2, i get this error undefined method '*' for nil:NilClass

Below is my controller code

```
def update 
    @studentprofile = StudentProfile.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @studentprofile.update_attributes(student_profile_params)
    redirect_to @studentprofile
end


def student_profile_params
        params[:normalisedgpa] = params[:initialgpa].to_s * 2

        params.require(:student_profile).permit(:status,:name,:imagethumbnail,:aboutme, :country, :state, :city,:language, :age,:gender,:initialgpa,:normalisedgpa,:universityname,:degree ,:degreetype ,:countryofdegree,:workexperience ,:wantstoworkin,:hasworkexperiencein,:permissiontoworkin,:currentlyemployed,:referencesuponrequest ,:worktype,:monthsspentabroadworking,:monthsspentabroadliving,:charitywork)
end
```

I have also tried placing "params[:normalisedgpa] = params[:initialgpa] * 2 " within the update method instead, as well as removing the ".to_s" and no luck

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controllers/student_profiles_controller.rb

```
def update
  @studentprofile = StudentProfile.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @studentprofile.update(student_profile_params)
  redirect_to @student_profile
end

def student_profile_params
  modified_params = params.require(:student_profile).permit(:status,:name,:imagethumbnail,:aboutme, :country, :state, :city,:language, :age,:gender,:initialgpa,:normalisedgpa,:universityname,:degree ,:degreetype ,:countryofdegree,:workexperience ,:wantstoworkin,:hasworkexperiencein,:permissiontoworkin,:currentlyemployed,:referencesuponrequest ,:worktype,:monthsspentabroadworking,:monthsspentabroadliving,:charitywork)
  modified_params[:normalisedgpa] = modified_params[:initialgpa] * 2
  modified_params
end
```

**Recommendations**

controllers/student_profiles_controller.rb

```
def update
  # use camelcase->underscore variable naming (i.e. @student_profile) instead of @studentprofile
  # use .find instead of .find_by so that it will show a Not Found page instead when such StudentProfile does not exist anymore
  @student_profile = StudentProfile.find(params[:id])

  # modifies @student_profile with the param values, but does not save yet to the database
  @student_profile.assign_attributes(student_profile_params)
  # manipulate the values here in the action and do not manipulate the params
  @student_profile.normalisedgpa = @student_profile.initialgpa * 2
  # handle validation errors, rather than silently failing when there is a validation error
  if @student_profile.save # if saving to the database successful
    # use flash messages (this is optional depending on your code)
    redirect_to @student_profile, success: 'Student Profile updated'
  else # if saving to the database not successful
    # the line below is just an example depending on your code
    render :edit
  end
end

private

def student_profile_params
  params.require(:student_profile).permit(:status,:name,:imagethumbnail,:aboutme, :country, :state, :city,:language, :age,:gender,:initialgpa,:normalisedgpa,:universityname,:degree ,:degreetype ,:countryofdegree,:workexperience ,:wantstoworkin,:hasworkexperiencein,:permissiontoworkin,:currentlyemployed,:referencesuponrequest ,:worktype,:monthsspentabroadworking,:monthsspentabroadliving,:charitywork)
end
```

Comment: great, that now updates the normalised gpa! However on the multipication front, it simply takes the input e.g 10.0 and turns it into 1010.0 instead of 20.0. Is my use of  x * 2 incorrect?

Comment: I updated my answer and removed `.to_s` as that turns the number into a string that is why you get 1010.

Answer (score 0):

As an append to the above answer from @Jay-Ar Polidario, you may need to add .to_i to the parameter in order to get a successful math operation.
For example, if my sale_price has the value of "1" and I simply add "parameter * 3", the result will be "111" instead of 3 ( 1 * 3 = 3).

i.e:

```
def sale_params
      modified_params = params.require(:sale).permit(:store_id, :item_id, :quantity, :sale_price)
      def sale_params
       modified_params = params.require(:sale).permit(:store_id, :item_id, :quantity, :sale_price)
 modified_params[:sale_price] =  modified_params[:quantity].to_i * 3.to_i
      modified_params
end
```